# Why does the json convertion expect String instead of Object when I use a List

Tags: android, json, android-volley, gson

This is my JSON info I am trying to convert into POJO
http://45.x.x.65/api/getCoins

Somehow, when I try to send a post request and try to convert json info into models, I get this annoying error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 156 path $.coins[0].currencies[0]
```

This is my request code to receive json file:

```
String url = "http://45.x.x.65/api/getCoins";
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    CoinStats coinStats = gson.fromJson(response, CoinStats.class);

//                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),coinStats.getExchange(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.getMessage());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/json");
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
```

These are the model files:

CoinStats

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;


public class CoinStats {

@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private Boolean result;
@SerializedName("exchange")
@Expose
private String exchange;
@SerializedName("from")
@Expose
private List<String> from = null;
@SerializedName("to")
@Expose
private List<String> to = null;
@SerializedName("coins")
@Expose
private List<Coin> coins = null;

public Boolean getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(Boolean result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public String getExchange() {
    return exchange;
}

public void setExchange(String exchange) {
    this.exchange = exchange;
}

public List<String> getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(List<String> from) {
    this.from = from;
}

public List<String> getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void setTo(List<String> to) {
    this.to = to;
}

public List<Coin> getCoins() {
    return coins;
}

public void setCoins(List<Coin> coins) {
    this.coins = coins;
}

}
```

Coin

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.List;

public class Coin {

@SerializedName("symbol")
@Expose
private String symbol;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("icon")
@Expose
private String icon;
@SerializedName("currencies")
@Expose
private List<Currency> currencies = null;

public String getSymbol() {
    return symbol;
}

public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public List<Currency> getCurrencies() {
    return currencies;
}

public void setCurrencies(List<Currency> currencies) {
    this.currencies = currencies;
}
}
```

Currency

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Currency {

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("price")
@Expose
private Double price;
@SerializedName("when")
@Expose
private Integer when;
@SerializedName("volume")
@Expose
private Integer volume;
@SerializedName("supply")
@Expose
private Double supply;
@SerializedName("market_cap")
@Expose
private Double marketCap;
@SerializedName("volume_24h")
@Expose
private Double volume24h;
@SerializedName("open_24h")
@Expose
private Double open24h;
@SerializedName("high_24h")
@Expose
private Double high24h;
@SerializedName("low_24h")
@Expose
private Double low24h;
@SerializedName("change_24h")
@Expose
private Double change24h;
@SerializedName("percentage_24h")
@Expose
private Double percentage24h;

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public Integer getWhen() {
    return when;
}

public void setWhen(Integer when) {
    this.when = when;
}

public Integer getVolume() {
    return volume;
}

public void setVolume(Integer volume) {
    this.volume = volume;
}

public Double getSupply() {
    return supply;
}

public void setSupply(Double supply) { this.supply = supply; }

public Double getMarketCap() {
    return marketCap;
}

public void setMarketCap(Double marketCap) {
    this.marketCap = marketCap;
}

public Double getVolume24h() {
    return volume24h;
}

public void setVolume24h(Double volume24h) {
    this.volume24h = volume24h;
}

public Double getOpen24h() {
    return open24h;
}

public void setOpen24h(Double open24h) {
    this.open24h = open24h;
}

public Double getHigh24h() {
    return high24h;
}

public void setHigh24h(Double high24h) {
    this.high24h = high24h;
}

public Double getLow24h() {
    return low24h;
}

public void setLow24h(Double low24h) {
    this.low24h = low24h;
}

public Double getChange24h() {
    return change24h;
}

public void setChange24h(Double change24h) {
    this.change24h = change24h;
}

public Double getPercentage24h() {
    return percentage24h;
}

public void setPercentage24h(Double percentage24h) {
    this.percentage24h = percentage24h;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing java.util.Currency rather than your own custom POJO, maybe that's why GSON can't construct the object properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there is some sort of issue on how the json you're getting is being formated. The section of the jsonString that should corresponding to coins is not translating correctly into a List. Any chance you could add the jsonstring you are converting to the post?

Comment: Just click on the link he posted

Comment: oh derp. missed that.

Comment: Could it be that it went wrong here when converting my json: jsonschema2pojo.org ??

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with the Json in your link, but since you're getting a JsonSyntaxException I'd set a break point and make sure the variable Response is exactly the string you are expecting.